# method to pass a dynamic string to a urlwithstringformat methos ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have a class which connect with a web service, and i created this method :

```
+(listingObject *) getDetailsForId : (NSString *) id {

    NSURL *url=[NSURL urlwithstringFormat : @"htt://mywebservic&id=%@",id];
}
```

it does not work plz some help

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/%@", id]]
```

...is a contrived example. It may be easier for readability to create your string on a separate line.

Comment: yes i know but the problem that i have a string url which contains an encrypted code which contains chars like "%2C" and the error say "replace %2C with %2@